# how to keep bash shell after finishing processing `-c` commands

Tags: bash, docker

Generally, my `/bin/bash` shell exits after finishing executing the commands specified in `-c` list. Is there a way to keep the shell still open after all the commands are done?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123103/how-to-keep-bash-running-after-command-execution

Comment: Really just `bash -c 'cmd1; cmd2; bash'`

Comment: @KamilCuk last command should probably be `exec bash`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: running a Docker image. I'd like pass it a `/bin/bash` with some commands. Then leave the shell open.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: exported functions are good enough